# Is it possible to enable sudo -u only for specific users?

Tags: sudo

I am trying to figure this out, but have not found a proper answer to this yet:

Is it possible to add a user to `/etc/sudoers` *only* with the rights to use `sudo -u` for *specific users*?

Comment: it's not clear to me: do you mean to limit the *target* users? E.g. permit say jsmith to run `sudo -u jbloggs foo` and `sudo -u jdoe foo` but not `sudo -u jchin foo`

Comment: It's clear that this question is about being about to `sudo -u someuser` and not `sudo -u someotheruser` or just `sudo` as root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can specify the users in the sudoers file

To let `youruser` run any command as the user `specificuser` do this:

```
youruser      ALL = (specificuser)    ALL
```

Answer (score 3):

From the `man sudoers` page:

> A Runas_Spec sets the default for the commands that follow it.  What
>   this means is that for the entry:
>
> ```
>     dgb    boulder = (operator) /bin/ls, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/lprm
> ```
>
> The user dgb may run /bin/ls, /bin/kill, and /usr/bin/lprm -- but only
>   as operator.  E.g.,
>
> ```
>     $ sudo -u operator /bin/ls.
> ```

I'm running sudo-1.7.4p5-4.fc15.x86_64